# Where is logstash classpath in windows?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I've spent hours with google trying to select data from a table of my postgres and insert it to elasticsearch (ES) by logstash in windows. Logstash didn't see driver class where I tried to determine jar by

```
jdbc_driver_library
```

option

Answer (score 1):

Next I removed that line and then I saw "enable to find this jar in logstash classpath" error. Where is It in windows?! The location is:

> [disk]:[logstash_folder]\logstash-core\lib\jars

Logstash is trying to find them there, so we need to put jars to this folder. After that everything works right and correct.

ES/Logstash v6